# g++ and clang++ different behaviour with initialization of C-style array of class types

Tags: c++, arrays, g++, language-lawyer, clang++

I suppose it's a g++ bug but I'm asking for confirmation.

The following code:

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::complex<double>  ac[10] = 23.5;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << ac[i] << ", ";

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

fails to compile on clang++ 3.5 with

> "error: array initializer must be an initializer list")

but compiles, without errors or warnings, with g++ 4.9.2.

The output of the g++ compiled executable is

```
(23.5,0), (23.5,0), (23.5,0), (23.5,0), (23.5,0), (23.5,0), (23.5,0), (23.5,0), (23.5,0), (23.5,0),
```

so this array initialization

```
std::complex<double>  ac[10] = 23.5;
```

work as initialization of every element of the array with the value on the right of the equal sign (and, I suppose, could be useful, if it would a standard accepted feature)

If I substitute the `std::complex<double>` array with a `double` array

```
double  ac[10] = 23.5;
```

g++ gives an error similar to the clang++ one:

> "error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer".

Another case: an array of vectors

```
std::vector<double>  ac[10] = std::vector<double>(3, 0.5) ;
```

g++ compiles it (and initialize every vector in the array) and clang++ give the usual error.

So I suppose it's a g++ bug occurring only with initialization of array of class (struct?) types. I'm asking for confirmation.